# Storyboard animation does not animate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have created a custom control, its purpose is to display current status of a task, the part of changing the selection without the animation is done, what I am struggling with, is the animation. It does not play the whole sequence which should be: State 1: Minimize => Change Foreground to gray | => State 2: Change Foreground to white => Highlight. Instead, it seems to skip a Storyboard.

The problem lies in the code below and I don't know what I am doing wrong here, I am pretty novice to XAML, and I'm sure I have done something stupid:

```
<UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Background="#252E3B">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="text1" Text="State 1" Grid.Row="0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="text2" Text="State 2" Grid.Row="1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                 </Grid>
            </Border>

            <!-- Triggers: here lies the problem -->
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!-- State 1 -->

                <!-- State 1 Selected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value1}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Selected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                To="White"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                <!-- Make font bigger -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                 From="15"
                                                 To="30" 
                                                 BeginTime="0:0:0.3"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <!-- State 1 Unselected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value1}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Unselected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Make font smaller -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                 From="30"
                                                 To="15" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                To="Gray"
                                                BeginTime="0:0:0.6"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>


                <!-- State 2 -->

                <!-- State 2 Selected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Selected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                To="White"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                <!-- Make font bigger -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                 From="15"
                                                 To="30" 
                                                 BeginTime="0:0:0.3"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <!-- State 2 Unselected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Unselected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Make font smaller -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                 From="30"
                                                 To="15" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                To="Gray"
                                                BeginTime="0:0:0.6"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **The Problem**

The problem was, when trying to animate one storyboard, the last one didn't stop, therefore the storyboard which was supposed to start did not

## **The Solution**

For another storyboard to animate we need to stop last animated storyboard, to do this, we have to set a name for all of the `<BeginStoryboard>`, after this when we start a new storyboard (`<BeginStoryboard>`) we should call other `<StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1"/>` to stop before the `<BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard2">`

## **The Code**

```
<!-- State 1 -->

                <!-- State 1 Selected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value1}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Selected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardUnselected1"/>

                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardSelected1">
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                To="White"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                <!-- Make font bigger -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                 From="15"
                                                 To="30" 
                                                 BeginTime="0:0:0.3"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <!-- State 1 Unselected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value1}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Unselected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardSelected1"/>

                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardUnselected1">
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Make font smaller -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                 From="30"
                                                 To="15" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text1"
                                                To="Gray"
                                                BeginTime="0:0:0.6"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>


                <!-- State 2 -->

                <!-- State 2 Selected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Selected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardUnselected2"/>

                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardSelected2">
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                To="White"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                <!-- Make font bigger -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                 From="15"
                                                 To="30" 
                                                 BeginTime="0:0:0.3"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <!-- State 2 Unselected -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="{x:Static core:StatusState.Unselected}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardSelected2"/>

                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardUnselected2">
                            <Storyboard>

                                <!-- Make font smaller -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                 From="30"
                                                 To="15" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <!-- Change Font Color -->
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="text2"
                                                To="Gray"
                                                BeginTime="0:0:0.6"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
```